# How can I have value types that map to nullable database columns in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullable

I have the following Entity model:

```
public class Todo  
{  
    [Required]  
    public int ID { get; set; }  
    public int OrderId { get; set; } //Not required  
    public string Description { get; set; }  
    public bool Finished { get; set; }  
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }  
    public int Priority { get; set; } //Not required  
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }  
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }  
}
```

In the corresponding database table all of the fields are created as "not null". I want to allow some of the fields to be null. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the database side, you will have to change the fields you want to be optional so that they can be null. The ALTER TABLE statement will do the trick.

```
ALTER TABLE Todo
ALTER COLUMN OrderId int NULL

ALTER TABLE Todo
ALTER COLUMN Priority int NULL
```

On the application side, you need to use [nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx). Try this:

```
public class Todo
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? OrderId { get; set; } //Not required
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Finished { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int? Priority { get; set; } //Not required
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

A nullable type is a variation of a regular value type with the difference that it can be null. In your code you can test for null with the [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) property:

```
int? foo= 42;
Console.WriteLine(foo.HasValue); // prints True
Console.WriteLine(foo.Value); // prints 42
int? bar = null;
Console.WriteLine(bar.HasValue); // prints False
Console.WriteLine(bar.Value); // throws InvalidOperationException
```

All operators on that type are lifted, meaning that you can still do arithmetic with them:

```
int? foo = 23;
int? bar = 17;
int? foobar = foo + bar;
Console.WriteLine(foobar); // Prints 40
int? baz = null;
int? foobaz = foo + baz + bar; // If any of them is null, the result will be null.
Console.WriteLine(foobaz); // Prints null
```

Comment: Works like a charm! The questionmark did the trick. Thank you! :-)